# Is "Didn't you have a meeting to attend to?" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, questions

Is the sentence "Didn't you have a meeting to attend to" grammatically correct?

Answer (score 10):

It's grammatical, but it may not mean what you think it means. *Attend to* means 'to see to, to look after'. It doesn't mean 'be present at'. For that you use *attend* with a direct object and without the preposition *to*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is completely correct. It is the equivalent of

> You had a meeting to give your attention to, did you not?
>   I have some urgent business to attend to.

I think your confusion might stem form your understanding of [to attend](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/attend)

> 1. to be present at (an event, meeting, etc)
> 2. (when: intr, foll by to) to give care; minister
> 3. (when: intr, foll by to) to pay attention; listen

There is no "to" built into the definition of attend; in usage, attend *to* is very common.